# Regex expression for PO Box in .javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to fire an onchange event from my asp:textbox so if someone enters PO Box in the text box then a panel becomes visible saying that PO box is not allowed. Somehow, the regex is not checking the PO box. I Tested the code in onTextChanged event in code behind and it works fine, but its failing in JavaScript.:

```
<asp:TextBox  ID="txtadd" runat="server"  onChange="addchange();" ></asp:TextBox>
```

my panel is like so:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnltest" runat="server" >
    
        PO box not allowed
    </div>

</asp:Panel>
```

below is my Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function addchange() {
            
            var add = document.getElementById('txtadd').value; 
            alert(add);
            var postalRGEX = /?i)\b(?:p(?:ost)?\.?\s*(?:[o0](?:ffice)?)?\.?\s*b(?:[o0]x)?|b[o0]x/;
            var result = postalRGEX.test(add);
            if (result == true) {
                document.getElementByID('<%=pnltest.ClientID%>').style.display = "block";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementByID('<%=pnltest.ClientID%>').style.display = "none";
            }

        }
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Might not be the regex: `getElementByID` => `getElementById`

Comment: I can see the value of txtadd in the alert box